# Is it possible with core Java 7 to copy a file over smb using a user different from the one running the Java?

Tags: java, authentication, share, ntlm, smb

Java 7 and indeed earlier versions can copy files over SMB, but the Java app must be run by a user that has access to the SMB share.  I know of third party Java libraries that allow you to specify a username, domain, and password to gain access to a share that the user running the Java app does not have access to.  The question: Can I, at run time, perform NTLM authentication for SMB shares using core Java the way you can for an HTTP connection using core Java?

Comment: Core java doesn't contain anything *that* specific. You will need some 3rd-party library to do this.